# How to copy a range of cells to another column based on a For statement

Tags: excel, range

I am very new to `VBA` and I am trying to copy a range of dates in the first column of the sheet to another column. I am using a For command so the number of dates that actually appears can change based on an input in a different Cell.

Here's what I have so far:

[image: Here's what I have so far]

```
Sub Plus1_ForLoop()

Range("G:G").ClearContents

Dim num_months As Integer

num_months = Cells(3, 8) * 12 - 1

For i = 3 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F3:F1113")) - (num_months - 2)

    Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=product(F" & i & ":F" & i + num_months & ")^(1/" & Cells(3, 8) & ")-1"

Next i

For i = 3 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3:A1113")) - (num_months - 2)

    Cells(i, 9) = Range("A & i & :A & i + num_months & ")

Next i

End Sub
```

My question is in regards to the second For code. I know I did a terrible job of explaining but I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: please put the code in as text instead of a photo.  we can not copy paste a photo.

Comment: You're missing closing `"`: `Cells(i, 9) = Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + num_months & ")"`

Comment: a couple of things: `)"A & i & :A & i + num_months & ")` should be `"A" & i & ":A" & i + num_months )" but you cannot put a range of values in one range, so I am not sure what you are trying to do with that statement.

Comment: I am trying to put the range of values from Ai:A(i+num_months) in column I starting at row three (Cell(i, 9) in this case)